# Settings.settings save Pattern type

Tags: c#, string, save, settings

I am trying to define Patterns on which an E-Mail is saved, in code i have been quite succesfull doing it like this:

```
 string Pattern0 = SafeFileName(currMail.SenderName);
 string Pattern1 = string.Join(" ", currMail.Subject.Split(' ').Take(3).ToArray());
 string Pattern2 = (Convert.ToDateTime(currMail.CreationTime).ToString(" dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm"));
```

and then i tried to save the Patterns on Properties.Setting, I Chose string, but that makes everything a string, as opposed to making them useful like they are above.
Does anybody know what it is that i could use, to save the Settings above in the Settings.settings file.
Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: I don't think you can save such kind of expressions in Settings.settings, why not define public methods for the patterns?

Comment: could i save the method in the settings?

Comment: nope, you cannot save method in settings.  Why you insist on saving them in settings?

Comment: Because i Need the Patterns to be saved Permanently

Comment: if permantenly saving is your only purpose, you can define public methods or properties for them, instead of using Settings